# Spring security4 session

Tags: spring

I am new in Spring. I am using spring security4.I just want to know, how to prevent new session creation in spring with java configuration. I have tried almost all features of spring but somewhere I am missing something.My requirement is when one user is login with his/her credential then application must not allowed new session creation with same credential,it should display a message "Someone is already logged in". What happening in my application is, it is restricting user from new session creation,but without any message.Also, when the existing user logout,then also it is not allowing to login with same credential. Kindly Help.

Comment: Spring Session is the best solution. Please go through this http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/

Comment: Thanx Barath..Can u xplain with example,if possible.